# setting value for array object via index sets all array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a complex javascript object with an array. When I try to set the value for one attribute of an index, it's applied to all items of the array.

Here is a basic example:

```
var obj = new Object();    
obj.arr = [];
obj.arr[0] = {pos:[0,0]};
obj.arr[1] = {pos:[0,0]};
```

Now if i set a value for an attribute of the object, via a specific index,

```
obj.arr[0].pos = [10,10];
obj.arr[1].pos = [5,5];
```

Here it seems to be setting the value `[5,5]` for both items of the array. The resulting values are:

`console.log(obj.arr[0].pos)` returns `[5,5]`
and

`console.log(obj.arr[1].pos)` also returns `[5,5]`

My actual object is far more complex, but this is the basic idea of what's happening...

Any ideas?

Comment: on chrome works fine, what is your browser?

Comment: It works fine. You can see at http://jsfiddle.net/swzF9/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They share the same link, i.e. several variables/properties of an object are referring to the same value.

Exact answer (where's the error) depends on how your object is composed.

```
var nested = {a:1};
var obj = {arr:[]};
obj.arr[0] = {pos:0, n:nested};
obj.arr[1] = {pos:0, n:nested};

obj.arr[0].pos = 1;
obj.arr[1].pos == 1; // false
obj.arr[0].nested.a = 2;
obj.arr[1].nested.a == 2; // true
```

Assignment of the same array/object **literals** is not the same.

```
var a = [0];
var b = [0];
b[0] = 1;
a[0] == 1; // false
b = a;
a[0] = 2;
b[0] == 2; // true

a = b = [0];
a[0] = 1;
b[0] == 1; // true
```

Comment: not sure what you mean.. shouldn't the index value keep the two objects separate? How do they share the same link if they have different indexes?

Comment: Updated the question and fixed some typos.. Still not understanding the problem.

Comment: Your example gives the following output: `Object { pos=[2]}`
`Object { pos=[2], coords=[2]}`. Maybe, there's a place in code, where you do something like `obj.arr[0] = obj.arr[1]`.

Comment: im having trouble re-producing the issue on a smaller scale.. the above example was just to give you an idea of the problem im having with my actual project.. I think the above code actually works as intended, but my real world issue is with a much more complex object.

Comment: People make mistakes millions times more often than computers. Javascript always work the same way: if some composed value (array, object, etc) is assigned, it is assigned by reference. And since then both variables share the same composed value. And changing one of them also changes another.